# PHP stream_select(): unable to select [13]: Permission denied (max_fd=380)

Tags: php, email, permissions, smtp, phpmailer

I getting an error on my php page. The test page I'm running just sends a test email message via the PHPMailer library, and this is the error message when I run it:

`C:\TestMail>php -f testMail.php 2023-07-24 14:37:33     SERVER -> CLIENT: 2023-07-24 14:37:33     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_select(): unable to select [13]: Permission denied (max_fd=380) Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_select(): unable to select [13]: Permission denied (max_fd=380)SMTP server error: Connection failed. Detail: stream_select(): unable to select [13]: Permission denied (max_fd=380) SMTP code: 2`

What can it be ? Do you have ideas?

I checked the file permissions and there are no problems. The user which the php service started is also correct. I have no connection problems to the smtp server, telnet on port 25 works. I also restarted service but nothing.